# Saving and querying elements in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have two very simple classes, one is Store class which is coded as follows

**Store**

```
class Store
{
    public virtual int StoreID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

And the following is for storing the Items that are going to be stored in the Store

**Item**

```
class Item
{
    public virtual int ItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Store StoreID { get; set; }        
}
```

The mappings with Fluent Nhiberate are as follows

**StoreMap**

```
class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
{
   public StoreMap()
   {
       Id(x => x.StoreID).Column("idStore").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
       Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable();

       HasMany(x => x.ItemID).KeyColumn("idItem").Inverse().Table("Item").AsSet().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

**ItemMap**

```
class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
       Id(x => x.ItemID).Column("idItem").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
       Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable();
       Map(x => x.Price).Column("Price").Default("0");
       Map(x => x.Quantity).Column("Quantity").Default("0");
       References(x => x.StoreID).Column("idStore");
    }
}
```

Now when I want to save two Items and a new Store, I do it with the following, but I don't know if there is a simple/better way to do so

```
Store s = new Store{...}
Item i1 = new Item {
     Name = "Item 1",
     ItemID = 1,
     Price = 100,
     Quantity = 1,
     StoreID = s
};
Item i2 = new Item {
     Name = "Item 2",
     ItemID = 2,
     Price = 100,
     Quantity = 1,
     StoreID = s
};
trans = session.BeginTransaction();
session.SaveOrUpdate(s);
session.SaveOrUpdate(i2);
session.SaveOrUpdate(i1);
//Commit changes
trans.Commit();
session.Flush();
session.Close();
```

And when I query to get all the data from the store, only the first Item shows in the list of items...

```
Store s = session.QueryOver<Store>().Where(x => x.StoreID == 1).SingleOrDefault<Store>();
```

**So my question is how should I query and save in order to get as minimum lines of code as possible and to get both Items in the list of the store?**

Comment: One thing to note is that an alternative is to just add the items to the store `Items` collection and then you should only have to save the Store entity (thanks to the `Cascade.SaveUpdate()` in your Store Items mapping).

Comment: You already properly use `cascade` *(I do use all with orphans, but..)*. That means, no need to call session save on items. They will be persisted.. just if we also add them into Store's collection `Items`

Comment: Ok, I've changed that adding the `Item` elements to the list of the `Store` list. But I still can't have both items at the list when I query to get the Store element with `Store s = session.QueryOver<Store>().Where(x => x.StoreID == 1).SingleOrDefault<Store>();`

Answer (score 0):

- For saving, because of the way you've mapped the entities,
  specifically because of the cascade option set
  (`.Cascade.SaveUpdate()`), you can happily remove
  `session.SaveOrUpdate(i2);` and `session.SaveOrUpdate(i1);`. Just
  saving `s` will save those automatically.
- To maintain the OO semantics, you need to add `item`s to `store. Effectively, it means adding these two lines:

  ```
  s.ItemID.Add(i1);
  s.ItemID.Add(i2);
  ```
- You can use `using` statement to simplify session creation and destruction (closing) neatly.

The final code will be like this:

```
    Store s = // as defined earlier;
    Item i1 = // as defined earlier;
    Item i2 = // as defined earlier;

    s.ItemID.Add(i1);
    s.ItemID.Add(i2);

    using (var session = NhConfig.GetSession())
    {
        var trans = session.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(s);

            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }

    // Later when you need to query
    using (var session = NhConfig.GetSession())
    {
        Store store = session.QueryOver<Store>().Where(x => x.StoreID == 1).SingleOrDefault();
        foreach (var item in store.ItemID) // store.ItemID.Count == 2.
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Item - Id: {item.ItemID}. Name: {item.Name}. Store ID: {item.StoreID.StoreID}.");
        }
        /* The above loop will print:
           Item - Id: 1. Name: Item 1. Store ID: 1.
           Item - Id: 2. Name: Item 2. Store ID: 1.
        */
    }
```

**On the mapping files...**

`ItemMap` can remain the way you defined it. However, `StoreMap` has a little bug you need to fix.

Change the line:

```
HasMany(x => x.ItemID).KeyColumn("idItem").Inverse().Table("Item").AsSet().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

to

```
HasMany(x => x.ItemID).KeyColumn("idStore").Inverse().AsSet().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

Notice what changed: the .KeyColumn is now named "idStore" instead of "idItem". The key column name on the `.HasMany(...)` side must correspond to the column name on the `.References(...)` side.

`.Table("Item")` is redundant since by default, "Item" will be the table name for the class called `Item`. Since you didn't mess with the table name in `ItemMap`, the default rule applies (unless you implemented a `Convention` for class/table names).

**Final notes:**

1. NHibernate now support `IQueryable<T>` through `session.Query<T>()`;
   so you can use it instead of `session.QueryOver<T>()`. If you're
   already used to writing Linq queries or if you're coming from EF
   world, you can just continue writing Linq queries like you
   normally do. There are a few times when Linq won't meet your need and you have to use `QueryOver`. There are even fewer times when `QueryOver` won't meet your need and you have to use `CreateCriteria`. Sometimes, none of those will be good for you and you have to write raw sql. But most of the time, including in this case, Linq will get you where you're going.
2. NHibernate also now support `async/await` pattern. All you need is add `using NHibernate.Linq;` and they'll become available. For this code, you can use `SaveOrUpdateAsync()` and `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` APIs instead of the non-async versions.
3. Since you're using Fluent NHibernate, consider using AutoMapping. Trust me, writing mapping files is no fun and you want to only write one when you absolutely have to.